# That only works in a Server Component || how to change next/headers to use client

Tags: next.js

I have multiple pages and components, most of this  is marked as "use client" because i  use state and useeffect in this  for most of operations and I cant now edit this with use server because is to many changes. And this hook i need to use on each page. (because this check subscriptions status etc)

Now I try implement auth, i have hooks:
`import { getSession, getUserDetails, getSubscription } from '@/app/supabase-server';`

but when I add this  in pages / components I have most of complications and everytime i get error:
`You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.`

How to edit to get cookies as client side or how to write new function directly to page to check example if  auth user session?

```
import { Database } from '@/types_db';
import { createServerComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { cache } from 'react';

export const createServerSupabaseClient = cache(() =>
  createServerComponentClient<Database>({ cookies })
);

export async function getSession() {
  const supabase = createServerSupabaseClient();
  try {
    const {
      data: { session }
    } = await supabase.auth.getSession();
    return session;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would refactor the pages to be server components and move the client code to a component you use in the pages

Comment: what do you think about retrive getSession instand of hook then from api  fetch? ( I can rewrite in some days but temporary i need do as quickly as possible)

Comment: You could try to add `"user server"` in the function as a quick fix but I don't know where the headers are needed.